# How do you jump to next error in the project in Intellij?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I know you can use F2 to jump to the next error in the same file but how do you jump to the next error in the project even if it's in a different file?

I've done a major refactoring which affected a parent class and so all subclasses need to be edited. Is there an easy way to go from one error to the next, even if it's in the next class, with a hotkey?

Answer (score 6):

Besides navigating through "Messages Build" window errors with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd> or <kbd>↓</kbd>, the errors can be shown by building the project via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F9</kbd> every time you fix one.

Since an edit in one file may lead to a fix in another one, this will guaranteed skip such false-positives directing to an actual compile-time error.

Make sure the option

> File | Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Compiler | Automatically show first error in editor

enabled, to use such approach.

[image]

An operation of directory clearing on rebuild can be disabled to speed up bugfixing process, though it's not recommended not to clear the output directory during development.

Answer (score 0):

I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd> to navigate through the messages in the Make window

It navigates through the "messages" not just errors. So if you have warnings in your project, that could also come in the way.

If that's the case you can use the hide warnings button.

Is this is what you need?

Comment: How do you navigate to and from the make window? That being said the problems window shows the compiler errors, but either way you still need to get from the code to that window with a hotkey otherwise you're back to using the mouse between each error