# "Automatically show first error in editor" missing in Android studio

Tags: android-studio

Currently after a failed compilation I need to manually go to the first error - which is suboptimal. It was once different so I tried to find the setting hinted here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/49686414/322642

But this option is missing for me:

[image: missing option]

There are hints that it was once there though:

[image: traces]

but I cannot choose this option.It leads me to the above settings screen and there this option is missing.

Also a "global F2" could help - but I do not find a way to get this.

Comment: Some settings are weird; if you close the project so you get to the project list/no open project state, and go to settings there, you could see if you can find it there. I remember this one setting (pretty sure it was annotation processing) that was (is?) only available through there

Comment: Thanks - this worked. If you add this as an answer I will accept it. That said - there I saw this box is ticked but it does not jump to the first error after compiling as expected

Comment: Just went and checked in IntelliJ; the setting is there. I've noticed several IntelliJ features that either don't work, or aren't included. I'll see if I can reproduce the issue in AS though -- if it doesn't work, it might be by design, or some other missing setting somewhere

Answer (score 1):

In order to toggle it, it needs to be changed in the default settings, which can be accessed from the home screen (close all projects), and by clicking on settings from there.

You might also have it listed under File -> Other settings -> Default Settings.

Android Studio has a bunch of settings that aren't included in the project settings. I honestly don't know why, but Android Studio seems more and more like it actively excludes IntelliJ features.

---

It not working, however, seems to be an entirely different issue, and it might be a bug in AS/IntelliJ -- I can't get it to work properly in either.

Comment: Thanks - but I do not see "default settings" in file -> other settings. The answer you commented before was working for me.